# Want to send a excel file and other params from javascript to python server in xhr POST request

Tags: javascript, python

I have a front page with some input boxes and a file upload button for uploading a file.
I pack them in a form data and send.
There is a python server using http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler receiving this POST request.
What I read on the server is data with a mime boundary , and all other params.
I just want to read the params separately, and read the file stream separately. It doesnt seem possible with this class.
How do I read only the input file ?

Comment: I'd use a proper web server like Django or flask.

Comment: it would be much simpler with web framework like `Flask` or `Django` - ie `request.files`, `request.post`, etc.. And now you have to do all on your own.

Comment: I'm leaning towards Flask too, the thing is I have this BaseHTTPRequestHandler  wrapped up in a class that starts up a multi threaded server and does a lot of our custom business logic .. so it will not be a straightforward replace. But definitely seems like the way forward, Thank you.